# I need to warp a long image into a 2d circle (webGL). Distortion is expected

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to take a long (max resolution) image and wrap it into a circle.  So imagine bending a steel bar so that it is now circular with each end touching.

[image: quick and dirty illustration]

I have been banging my head against threejs for the last 8 hours and have so far managed to apply the image as a texture on a circle geometry, but can't figure out how to apply the texture to a long mesh and then warp that mesh appropriately.  The warping doesn't need to be (and shouldn't be) animated.  What we basically have is a 360 panoramic image that we need to "flatten" into a top-down view.

In lieu of sharing my code (as it's not significantly different), I've so far been playing around with this tutorial:

http://www.johannes-raida.de/tutorials/three.js/tutorial06/tutorial06.htm

And I do (I think) understand the broad strokes at this point.

Other things I've tried is to use just canvas to slice the image up into strips and warp each strip... this was horribly slow and I couldn't get that to work properly either!

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: It would be easier to give you suggestions if you post an image of what you want the texture to look like on the mesh and what it currently looks like.

Comment: A canvas version : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/hto1s6fy/

Comment: @GameAlchemist can you please put this in an answer really quick so that I can give you proper credit?  And thank you!

Comment: Any easy way to remove Moire patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's a function using canvas's context2d that does the job.

The idea is to go around all the circle by a small angular step and to draw a thin slice of 'texture' along the circle radius.

To make it faster, only way i see is to compute by hand the transform to do one single setTransform instead of all this stuff.
The step count is optimal with step = atan(1, radius)
(if you do the scheme it's obvious : to go one y up when you're radius far from the center then tan = 1/radius => step angle = atan(1, radius).)

fiddle is here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/hto1s6fy/

A small example with a cloudy landscape :

[image]

```
// draw the part of img defined by the rect (startX, startY, endX, endY) inside 
//   the circle of center (cx,cy) between radius (innerRadius -> outerRadius) 
// - no check performed -
function drawRectInCircle(img, cx, cy, innerRadius, outerRadius, startX, startY, endX, endY) {
    var angle = 0;

    var step = 1 * Math.atan2(1, outerRadius);
    var limit = 2 * Math.PI;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    while (angle < limit) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.rotate(angle);
        ctx.translate(innerRadius, 0);
        ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
        var ratio = angle / limit;
        var x = startX + ratio * (endX - startX);
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, startY, 1, (endY - startY), 0, 0, 1, (outerRadius - innerRadius));
        ctx.restore();
        angle += step;
    }
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: and how to do the opposite?

Answer (score 3):

Here's also a shader version: [Shadertoy - Circle Distortion](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsSSDz)

This is the actual code:

```
#define dPI 6.28318530718   // 2*PI
#define sR 0.3              // small radius
#define bR 1.0              // big radius

void main(void)
{
// calc coordinates on the canvas
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy*2.-vec2(1.);
    uv.x *= iResolution.x/iResolution.y;

// calc if it's in the ring area
    float k = 0.0;
    float d = length(uv);
    if(d>sR && d<bR)
        k = 1.0;

// calc the texture UV
    // y coord is easy, but x is tricky, and certain calcs produce artifacts
    vec2 tUV = vec2(0.0,0.0);

    // 1st version (with artifact)
    //tUV.x = atan(uv.y,uv.x)/dPI;

    // 2nd version (more readable version of the 3rd version)
    //float disp = 0.0;
    //if(uv.x<0.0) disp = 0.5;
    //tUV.x = atan(uv.y/uv.x)/dPI+disp;

    // 3rd version (no branching, ugly)
    tUV.x = atan(uv.y/uv.x)/dPI+0.5*(1.-clamp(uv.x,0.0,1.0)/uv.x);

    tUV.y = (d-sR)/(bR-sR);

// output pixel
    vec3 col = texture2D(iChannel0, tUV).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(col*k,1.);
}
```

So you could draw rectangle on the canvas and add this shader code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. I think it's always better to use the two-arguments version of atan ((atan(y,x)). I found that tUV.x = atan(uv.y,uv.x)/3.14; is rendering nice (first version, but divided by PI, not 2 PI).

Comment: It does thank you very much.  I'm going to go with the canvas version as I understand it better, but this is great :)

Comment: can you show us how to use this on codepen/jsfiddle or here using the snippets?